# LESS class name string interpolation not working

Tags: css, less, grid-layout, string-interpolation

I am currently translating my grid into LESS, but I can't seem to figure out string interpolation.

Here's helper class that is supposed to generate all my columns:

```
.createColumns (@colNumber+1) {}

.createColumns (@index) when (@index < @colNumber) {
    (~".col@{index}") {
         width: @baseWidth * @index;
    }

    .createColumns (@index + 1);
}

.createColumns (01);
```

Problem is, I get error that says something is wrong with this part `(~".col@{index}")`.

Here's the error message:

```
ParseError: Unrecognised input
in grid.css on line 17, column 4:
16    .createColumns (@index) when (@index < @colNumber) {
17        (~".col@{index}") {
18            width: @baseWidth * @index;
```

I have checked several examples and all use same syntax, so I'm not sure what I'm missing.
This was also one of my tries that resulted in an error:

```
.createColumns (@index) when (@index < @colNumber) {
    @class : "col"@index;
    .(@class) {
        width: @baseWidth * @index;
    }
.createColumns (@index + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escaped selector interpolation is deprecated in 1.4.x, use

```
.col@{index} {
     width: @baseWidth * @index;
}
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks! I tried every possible combination except that, even .col@index :)

Comment: Do not hesitate to read the official LESS site for breaking language changes as certain examples may be outdated.