# LESS generate comma separated class names

Tags: css, class, less

I know how I can generate separate class names like:

```
.class1 {
}

.class2{
}

.class2{
}
...
```

But if I want all of them to have 10 px margin, that generates lot's of repeated code. Can I generate something like:

```
.class1, .class2, .class3, ... {
    //Common properties
}
```

in LESS?

Comment: Why would you need to repeat yourself, though? Just have a single class that has common properties. An element can have multiple classes.

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri how?

Comment: An example would be `.class1 { .common; /* something else */ } .class2 { .common; /* something else */  }` and so on. LESS can nest.

Comment: @remyabel but I'm talking about compiled code. Now I have `.class1 {padding:10px;} .class2 {padding:10px;}...` instead of `.class1, .class2 {padding:10px;}`

Comment: `.common { padding: 10px; }

.class1, .class2 {
 .common;
}` produces `.class1,
.class2 {
  padding: 10px;
}
`

Comment: @remyabel But I want to generate `.class1, .class2` by loop, look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675359/less-class-name-string-interpolation-not-working

Comment: @Jinx: Why do you need so many class names?

Comment: @Blender grid system.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention that. You should make an edit. Take a look at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less They give a brief overview on how they accomplish their grid system using LESS.

Comment: @remyabel, I specifically ask: How can I generate class names separated by comma.

Comment: The SO link you posted and Bootstrap link I posted seem to cover what you want.

Comment: @remyabel, not really, but nvm.

Comment: If you're unable to do what you want in LESS itself, you can always write a one-time script or program to generate the code for you. (like a build script)

Comment: @remyabel I don't know if I can or can't. That's what I'm asking here.

Comment: Have you tried using @extend?

Comment: @ScottSimpson Perfect! Can you add this as your answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Less has recently added @extend functionality.
Try this:

```
:extend(.class-name)
```